# .NET Add header to response on index.html request?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI project called `Mensajes.Cliente` which contains an Angular application:

[image: Project structure]

For security reasons, I need to add 2 headers to every server response. Solved that adding the following to Global.asax:

```cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    Response.AddHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1");
}
```

When I call any of the controllers methods, the response does contain both headers, so that works fine.

But when I try to get the index.html as `foo.com/Mensajes.Cliente` or `foo.com/Mensajes.Cliente/index.html`, no header is set (it happens with all the static content as .js or .css files).

[image: Request response]

How can I add these headers to the response of **every** server request?

Must these headers be set in web.config or Global.asax configuration, or its a server configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The easiest way to set headers for all the content of site is in `web.config`. The `customHeaders` section under the`httpProtocol` in `system.webServer` will make sure that this header is included for all files and responses.

Example:

```
<system.webServer>
   <!--.......-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>    
    <!--.......-->
</system.webServer>
```

2. Another option is to create custom `HttpModule`. This way you have more control on the files and content to which headers needs to be appended.

Example:

```
public class CustomOrgHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //To add header only for Html files
       //You can add any condition as you need
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".html"))//css, js as you need
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1");
        }
    }
}
```

And register `CustomOrgHeaderModule` in `web.config` -

```
   <system.webServer>
       <!--.......-->
        <modules>
         <add name="CustomHeaderModule" type="SOFTEST.NET.API.Modules.CustomOrgHeaderModule" /><!--.SOFTEST.NET.API.Modules.CustomOrgHeaderModule is then FullNmae of the class MEANS Namesapce.CassName -->
       </modules>  
        <!--.......-->
    </system.webServer>
```

And you don need to set `Response.AddHeader` in `Global.asax` any more.